# Phase Lag Compensator

Tags: control, compensation, root-locus, pole-compensation

I have a question on lag compensators in general.

> Why do they increase both the rise time and the settling time? Is it due to the introduction of a slow pole?

Much thanks!

Comment: A lag compensator is typically a low pass filter.

Comment: I know but I still do not understand why it increases both the rise and settling time.

Comment: A low pass filter restricts high frequencies and edges (a la rise and fall time) become slugged because edges are regarded as having high frequency content.

Comment: If Im understanding correctly, if I consider a step input which consists of various frequency components then the system will restrict both the rise time and fall time

Comment: Yes it will. An edge is typically (and theoretically) an infinite spectrum of high frequencies.

Comment: Thank you very much, much appreciated!